# Youtube live stream fails after 4.6 hours when uploaded from Wowza with 24-bit audio timestamp

Tags: audio-streaming, rtmp, wowza, youtube-livestreaming-api, wowza-transcoder

We use Wowza to stream live video to AWS Elemental and Youtube using the rtmp protocol

Now, whenever we are streaming the Audio goes down after 4 hours 40 minutes. However, we generally have 6-8 hours of a stream.

The audio uses a 24-bit timestamp which translates to 4 hours 40 minutes. It is not an option for us to change the audio timestamp from the input stream.

Is there a way to override the input stream audio bits from a 24-bit value to a larger one say 32-bit.

Youtube live stream fails after 4.6 hours when uploaded from Wowza with a 24-bit audio timestamp

Comment: What are the source format and encoding settings?

Comment: @aergistal xdcam hd422